# How to overwrite part of url to subfolder with htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to overwrite

`domain.com/image?f=images/subfolder/image.ext`

to

`domain.com/images/subfolder/image.ext`

Any ideas how to reach this with htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+image\?f=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(images/.+)$ /image?f=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Sure, we are here to help out all newcomers on this wonderful forum.